# Count the total number of records before a specific day for the last N days in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores customer information including their registration date with the service. I would like to know the total number of subscribed customers (from the beginning of the service up until that day) at the end of the day for the past 10 days.

I imagine the solution would be something similar to a for loop, so the best I managed so far is the following:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT 
SET @Counter=1
WHILE ( @Counter <= 10)
BEGIN
   select try_convert(date, getdate()-@Counter), count(id)
   from Table_name
   where try_convert(date, registrationdate) <=  try_convert(date, getdate()-@Counter)
    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```

The problem with the above script is that it produces 10 different tables and I haven't been able to union them together. I'm fairly new to SQL so there might be a simpler solution that I'm missing!

The output I have in mind looks like this:

| date | total number registered |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-30 | 500,000 |
| 2022-01-29 | 499,800 |

Comment: Something is **terribly wrong** with your schema if you need to use TRY_CONVERT on every column. You should NOT get into the bad habit of using mathematical operators with dates - use DATEADD for that. Lastly you need a table containing the dates of interest - a tiny little "calendar". Search that term to find code that can build that dynamically. With a calendar, you simply outer join to your data to get a row for all dates and the count/sum you need in one query / resultset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with a loop. You would simply create an SQL select that selects them. ie:

```
select * 
from myTable 
where datediff(day, registrationDate, getdate()) <= 10;
```

EDIT: Question is edited to show the desired output now, then it would need a different way like:

```
select registrationDate, count(*) as TotalNumberRegistered 
    from myTable 
    where datediff(day, registrationDate, getdate()) <= 10
    group by registrationDate;
```

EDIT: If as P.Salmon said you were after a "running total" then you still can get it with a slight modification to code:

```
WITH dailyTotals(registrationDate, TotalNumberRegistered) AS 
     (
        SELECT   registrationDate, COUNT(*)
        FROM     myTable
        WHERE    DATEDIFF(DAY, registrationDate, GETDATE())<=10
        GROUP BY registrationDate
     )
SELECT registrationDate
   , SUM(TotalNumberRegistered) OVER (ORDER BY registrationDate) AS TotalNumberRegistered
FROM dailyTotals
Order by registrationDate desc; -- you want it to be ordered last date first?
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1286b7a81bdb65259ed4a650b1231865)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not what I'm looking for. Your answer computes the new customers registered in the last 10 days. What I want is the total registered before each date. the output I'm looking for is something like, "date": "total number"; "date-1": "total number" and so on.

Comment: @M.Elauzei Please provide table structure, some sample data, and desired results from that sample data (e.g. in a [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle)). This is much easier than people stabbing and you just saying "that's not what I want." Show us what you want with real data, not the query you tried that didn't work either.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I didn't just say "that's not what I want". I thanked him for his answer and clarified that it doesn't do what I had in mind. Also, the question DOES HAVE a table structure for how the output would look like.

Comment: The question DID NOT HAVE a table structure for how the output would look like when I saw and answered it. Editing to accommodate.

Comment: I suspect this is a cumulative sum over the 10 days with the first day being a sum of every one registered on or before day 1 rather than a sum by day..perhaps OP would comment.

Comment: @M.Elauzel output of a result is not what I meant by table structure. I’m not giving you crap, don’t be defensive, just trying to help you ask a more complete question (this time and next time) so people don’t waste time on answers you don’t want. Please see https://sqlblog.org/ask

Comment: @P.Salmon, that is not what I understood really but I will edit my question to include that case. Thanks.

Comment: @Cetin Basoz OP should really clarify and provide representative sample data..until he/she does so I may be just setting a hare running to no useful end.

Comment: @P.Salmon, yes, right. Anyway, now both cases are covered and might help to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use temp table, GROUP BY and INNER JOIN:

```sql
select try_convert(date, registrationdate) as registrationdate, count(1) as cnt
into #tmp
from Table_name
group by try_convert(date, registrationdate)

select top 10 t1.registrationdate, SUM(1) as total
from #tmp t1
inner join #tmp t2 on t1.registrationdate >= t2.registrationdate
group by t1.registrationdate
order by t1.registrationdate desc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @miXtr. this helped solve a similar problem I was stuck at.